# couchapp dosen't work! (node.couchapp.js)

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchapp

I have a problem: couchapp has been installed by me, but it works not too well.
I try to repeat shown here: http://vimeo.com/26147136 but:

```
master@master:~/WebDev/superblog$ couchapp push app.js http://localhost:5984/superblog
```

The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^

> Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the
>   NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
>       at Function. (module.js:376:11)
>       at Object. (/home/master/.node_libraries/couchapp@9999.0.0-LINK-b6f5885b/index.js:4:21)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
>       at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
>       at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
>       at require (module.js:368:17)
>       at Object. (/home/master/WebDev/superblog/app.js:1:79)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)

I don't know as it to correct. Help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not help you directly, but you can use Reupholster until node.couchapp.js runs for you.

http://reupholster.iriscouch.com/reupholster/_design/app/index.html

(Disclaimer: it is my project)

The format of the project is pretty much the same as node.couchapp.js, so you can get your couchapp development going, and switch back to the node version at any point. Reupholster is just a little easier to get running.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! i was gone development with PHP. it's more easy for me

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Kanso to push apps written to the node.couchapp.js API: http://kan.so/docs/Kanso_for_node.couchapp.js_and_reupholster_developers